# Rearranging or Shuffling Rows Based on Alternative Groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reorder rows based on group

My current dataframe -

```
name   value   group
a       10     group 1
d       20     group 1
b       20     group 2
e       10     group 2
c       30     group 3
f       30     group 3
```

I want output as reordering rows based on Alternating Groups

```
name   value   group
a       10     group 1
b       20     group 2
c       30     group 3
d       20     group 1
e       10     group 2
f       30     group 3
```

Comment: `df.sort_by("name")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby_cumcount`:

```
>>> df.assign(rank=df.groupby('group').cumcount()).sort_values('rank')

  name  value    group  rank
0    a     10  group 1     0
2    b     20  group 2     0
4    c     30  group 3     0
1    d     20  group 1     1
3    e     10  group 2     1
5    f     30  group 3     1
```

Obviously, you can drop the column `rank` by appending `.drop(columns='rank')`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a [`cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and a [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to do get the expected result :

```py
>>> df["group_cumcounts"] = df.groupby("group").cumcount()
>>> df.sort_values(["group_cumcounts"]).drop("group_cumcounts", axis=1)
    name    value   group
0   a          10   group 1
2   b          20   group 2
4   c          30   group 3
1   d          20   group 1
3   e          10   group 2
5   f          30   group 3
```

Comment: It's not necessary to `sort_values` by 'group' because `groupby` does it by default (`sort=True`)

Comment: Indeed ! I just tried it and the result is the same. I updated the answer, thanks @Corralien for this advice, and for your pythonist answer !

Comment: Thank you both! Appreciate your help.